# grails @BindUsing command Object

Tags: grails, data-binding, command-objects, grails-2.5

I am using grails 2.5.5 and the problem is when I'm using a command Object, I want to change the format of the data I get with the @BindUsing annotation.

```
@Validatable
class FooCommand extends BarCommand{
    @BindUsing({obj, source -> return source['foo'].collect{it['id']}})
    List<Long> foo

static constraints = {foo(nullable:true)}
}
```

the BindUsing closure never gets executed. What is the problem and how to solve?

```
JSONData = {"foo":[
                   {'id':5}, 
                   {'id':4}
                  ]
           }
FooCommand fooCommand = FooCommand(JSONData)
fooCommand.validate()
```

**EDIT:**
To be clear: the problem is that the data change from format,from list of maps, to just a list of longs. Is there a way to do this with the BindUsing or will i just have to do it in the controller each time?

Comment: I've created the command you mentioned, empty `BarCommand`, and simple controller with one action `def index(FooCommand foo) {}`
After running `http://localhost:8080/untitled/simpleController?foo={}` from my browser `BindUsing` closure is executing. Could you try to do the same manipulations?

Comment: I'll give it a try in the evening, how did you check if the bindUsing gets executed? I tried it with prints/logging.

Comment: I simply used breakout.

Comment: i do not have acces to breakpoints in debugmode because i can only run grails 2.5.5 in forked mode (havent set up forked debugger yet). I managed to confirm that in your case the bindUsing gets executed only if the databinding (not the constraints) would finish succesfully without the bindUsing.